# How can i filter column values?

Tags: r

I'm new in R and i was trying to filter data from my table using a specific keyword.
For example, I have a column "messages" and I want to get all data CONTAINING the word "apple" not only data exactly equal to "apple" and save it to a separate table. 
So I was wandering if there is a way for me to do this?

Comment: Use the `grep`,  i.e. `df2 <- df1[grep("\\bapple\\b", df1$messages),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
df2 <- df1[grep("\\bapple\\b", df1$messages),]
```